# How to change main file in package.json in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to Node.js and this is my first project in node. Now I have two main files.
For local envoirnment I have index.js file and for production envoirnment production.js. Now I want that when I run command npm start then automaticall file loaded according to envoirnment.

I done following changes in package.json

```
 "main": "process.env.APP_ENV==undeinfed ? index.js : server.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "process.env.APP_ENV==undeinfed ? index.js : server.js",
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

When I npm start command then I received following error

> > quick-create-post@1.0.0 start /home/php/fayvo/lambda/quick-create-post
> >     process.env.APP_ENV==undeinfed ? index.js : server.js
>
> sh: 1: process.env.APP_ENV==undeinfed: not found npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! errno
>   ENOENT npm ERR! quick-create-post@1.0.0 start:
>   `process.env.APP_ENV==undeinfed ? index.js : server.js` npm ERR! spawn
>   ENOENT npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the quick-create-post@1.0.0 start
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/.npm/_logs/2019-12-18T10_11_35_259Z-debug.log

Comment: whatever it is ..your `undefined` is wrong `undeinfed`. Check spelling

Comment: I suggest having a one main file that accounts current `process.env.APP_ENV` value and executes the correct logic per environment.

Comment: The scripts are cli commands, not javascript expressions, this will not work. Normally you would have a single main file in which you check environment variable NODE_ENV to determine how to start the app

Comment: top two answers makes sense, so better for you to create a new file and implemnt the logic to require the corresponding files according to the current environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest implementing a one `index.js` file that does all required branching inside explicitly without hidden logic inside `package.json` file. It will give much more readable and flexible approach.